# New tags: [OpenEXR], [ExifTool]

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently had a question [relating to video conversion](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19573) where the input format was OpenEXR and I used ExifTool for diagnostics. I think these would make helpful tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I see enough of a case for ExifTools specifically.  On EXR, is there really enough of a difference between EXR and OpenEXR to make it worth its own tag?  I've not personally worked with EXR, but it sounds like OpenEXR is just one particular implementation of an EXR encoder.  I'm not sure that is worth a specific tag either.

Comment: ah, I thought openexr was the "more correct" name - thanks for the feedback (including re exiftools)

Comment: @d3vid - it might be, like I said, I'm not familiar with the format itself.  If OpenEXR is the actual name and EXR itself has no meaning, then I wouldn't be opposed to changing the existing tag to be OpenEXR, but I'd want someone to verify that first.

Comment: OpenEXR, as per wiki, is an ILM created image format, with EXR being shorthand. OpenEXR could be created but EXR suffices, I think.